# validatorJS- not validating password confirm

Tags: forms, validation, flask

I was developing a simple app with sign up and login facility using python Flask. I have used validator.js for client side validation. The problem i am facing is the the confirm password validation works when the html file is opened on its own but when i render it from flask it always shows that passwords dont match. Here is the project link [github link to my project](https://github.com/guruvyasa/placementPortal.git)

Other validations are working as expected.

The html for the fields looks like this:

```
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" data-minlength="6" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
      <span class="help-block">Minimum of 6 characters</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPasswordConfirm" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very simple mistake. The index page had two forms with password fields and i had given both the same id. Given them different ids solved the problem